# HTTP Archive (.har) log reader?

Tags: software-recommendation, kubuntu

I've recently moved to kubuntu. Is there any app to read HTTP Archive Log (.har). I know about this http://www.softwareishard.com/har/viewer/. I'm looking for an offline app to view .har files.

Thanks,
jeetesh

Answer (score 1):

Of all the offline tools that work on Ubuntu, the [HTTP Archive Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-archive-viewer/ebbdbdmhegaoooipfnjikefdpeoaidml?hl=en) Chrome extension is probably the easier to install (the other alternatives are web apps that you can host locally, and command line tools which don't give you a useful overview). It's nothing fancy, but it can display a timeline similar to the one in Chrome Developer Toolbar's Network tab, and can show the headers and body of each request and response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HAR Viewer](https://github.com/janodvarko/harviewer)

> HAR Viewer is a web application (PHP) that allows to visualize HTTP tracing logs based on  HTTP Archive format (HAR). These files contain recorded information about HTTP traffic
>    performed by web pages. A HAR log can be created by HTTP sniffer tools such as Firebug.

It's still web-based, somehow, but you can use it on a local server

Comment: That's the same viewer that's mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

HAR files appear to be JSON files, so for basic analysis you can parse the JSON manually.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still interested, the VScode HAR viewer (both of them) is unable to display websocket transports included in HAR, and Google's analyser lacks a lot of features and some would not trust it with their data. The most convenient way I found is to load up `about:blank` in your browser, open DevTools in a separate window and import the file.

Answer (score -1):

there are a number of tools / apps that can help visualize `.har` files and data:

- [ChromeHAR](https://ericduran.github.io/chromeHAR/)
- [harview](http://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2013/09/16/quick-n-dirty-har-http-archive-viewer/)
- [HTTP Archive Reader (for Firebug)](http://www.brothersoft.com/http-archive-reader-350659.html)
- [HTTP Watch](https://www.httpwatch.com/)

you might want to check [Har.tech](http://har.tech/) for a complete list of resources

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/492065)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @guntbert I've updated my response with more details.

Comment: HTTP Archive Reader and HTTP Watch are Windows-only (and the latter costs something ridiculous). harview just lists the requests - it's not a "viewer" in the sense that the softwareishard one is. ChromeHAR is not an offline viewer (you can host it locally, but then you can do that with the softwareishard viewer aswell).